# VS Code Intellisense and Node JS strange behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense

EDIT: This has been reported on the VS Code repo. To see the issue and watch a video of the bug, go here https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/68733

---

I'm not sure if this is a bug or something related to JavaScript that I'm unaware of. Basically, VS Code Intellisense fails to list any methods of Node modules I require depending on the order I require the module. This affects just about all modules and files I require.

This will show Intellisense prompts for the http module.

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');

http.
```

This won't:

```
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

http.
```

All that changed was the order I required the modules. Is this a VS Code bug or a property of JavaScript/Node I'm not getting?

---

[image]
[image]

I haven't messed with many settings in VS Code if at all. I will continue to looks through my settings to see if I can find anything relevant.

Comment: That is odd. In your second example, does intellisense work for `fs`?

Comment: It's a plain obvious bug in VS Code. Create an issue in the git repo (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode).

Comment: @NemoStein Not obvious to someone learning Node and Javascript for the first time... Could be related to Emmet or TypeScript extensions perhaps.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine No it doesn't. Actually, it appears to now be completely random. I'm having it work and fail in reverse order now. Guess that confirms it as unexpected behavior indeed...

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this in my VS Code install. Maybe extensions are involved. **Edit: Now I got it (coping the whole line)**

Comment: could be different line endings that are causing some parsing error then

Comment: Scratch my previous comment. It is totally random. Okay thanks guys, I'll mess around with my extensions I guess and get back to you :) I'll also try to find SOME consistency.

Comment: After your last comment I was able to reproduce the issue here! Please, open a issue in the repo.

Comment: @NemoStein Okay will do! Just to note, I am able to reproduce it without any copying. So I still don't know what is causing it, but I'll make a bug report. Thanks for the bug confirmation!

Comment: Interesting.. could you share the issue id with us?

Comment: @ııı Here is the issue with a video included https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/68733